# The derivative anomaly in Mathematica 13, showing in the Plot[] function

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, evaluation

Edit:
Still inexplicably, it was found that in the `Plot[]` functions, showing a correct curve plot for the expression computing the derivative incorrectly, when 'Evaluate' is replaced with 'Simplify', the remaining incorrect curve is also plotted correctly. An illustrating plot is added at the end.

This question is related to the Mathematica 13 derivative flaw, discussed in the following pages:

1. [Derivative function anomaly in Mathematica v. 13.1 (identified as a DifferenceRoot issue)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/275507/derivative-function-anomaly-in-mathematica-v-13-1-identified-as-a-differencero)
2. [A workaround needed to overcome the Derivative function anomaly in Mathematica 13](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/275793/a-workaround-needed-to-overcome-the-derivative-function-anomaly-in-mathematica-1)

The issue is further illustrated with an apparent inconsistency, revealed in different plots of the same derivative expression.

The examples, based on the same sample expression, as in the discussions, referenced above, are set as follows:

```
expr=-x 10^(-x^3); 
exprD=D[expr,{x,n}];
f[x_]:=-x 10^(-x^3);
exprDf=Derivative[n][f][x];
```

[image: Q3_1]

The general derivative expressions above, have been identified as causing a problem, apparently due to `DifferenceRoot[]`. A summary of the anomalous results is shown below for continuity and information. It illustrates the miscalculated derivatives for $n=0$, when set as a replacement rule for n.
[image: Q3_2]

The following shows that for $n=1$ all forms of evaluating the derivative produce correct results:
[image: Q3_3]

The plots of the correct derivative expressions for $n=0$ are shown for reference below with `D[expr,{x,0}]` and `Derivative[0][f][x]`:
[image: Q3_4]

```
 Plot[Evaluate[{D[expr, {x, 0}], Derivative[0][f][x]}], {x, -1, 1.5}, 
     PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

[image: Q3_5]

The anomalous behaviour takes a different 'shape' when the  two expressions, `D[expr,{x,n}]/.n->0;` and `Derivative[n][f][x]/.n->0;` are used to plot the corresponding derivatives. Evaluating the derivatives in the following two different ways, both result in the incorrect expression for $n=0$:
[image: Q3_6]

However, when the same evaluation is done within the `Plot[]` function, `Evaluate[exprD]/.n->0` produces the correct graphical result:

```
Plot[{Evaluate[exprD] /. n -> 0, Evaluate[exprD /. n -> 0]}, {x, -1, 
  1.5}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

[image: Q3_7]

The same 'anomaly' is repeated with the evaluated expressions `Derivative[n][f][x]]/.n->0` and `[Derivative[n][f][x]/.n->0]`. Both produce the incorrect results for $n=0$ as shown below:
[image: Q3_8]

However, when the same evaluation is done within the `Plot[]`, `Evaluate[Derivative[n][f][x]]/.n->0` produces the correct graphical result:

```
Plot[{Evaluate[Derivative[n][f][x]] /. n -> 0, 
  Evaluate[Derivative[n][f][x] /. n -> 0]}, {x, -1, 1.5}, 
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

[image: Q3_9]

```
Plot[{Evaluate[Derivative[n][f][x]]/.n->0,Simplify[Derivative[n][f][x]/.n->0]},{x,-1,1.5},PlotLegends->"Expressions"]
```

[image: Q3_10]

The question is:

What 'hidden' procedure (order of computation?), implemented with the `Plot[]` function, apparently circumvents the flaw that shows when computing the 0th derivative with a replacement rule $n->0$?

Comment: Your second, third, fourth, fifth, and sixth uses of `Evaluate` are incorrect (that is, ineffective). You might as well have left them out.

Comment: @Michael E2, Deficiencies in my using code and in my explanations are likely. Sorry. I am aware that expressions and plots can be obtained without Evaluate. My question is about inconsistent derivative evaluation, which is unexpectedly 'correct'. The two expressions, preceding the 2nd and 3rd plots produce incorrect derivatives with or without Evaluate. The 'mystery' then is why Plot of the same expressions results in one of the derivative curves being of a correctly computed derivative!

Comment: …Just a suggestion: it's better to make the question shorter, you don't need to illustrate those trivial and expected behaviors, that'll make the question easier to read and more attractive.

Comment: Then, to close voters: though the question is unnecessarily long, the underlying issue is non-trivial, it's not simple at all. Please see my answer for more details. Vote to reopen. @MichaelE2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Three issues here:

1. You've accidentally found another workaround for the bug of `DifferenceRoot` discussed in [the linked post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/275513/1871).
2. `Plot` is a function that owns `HoldAll` attribute.
3. Though `Plot` is a function that owns `HoldAll` attribute, it still evaluates its arguments in a somewhat non-standard way. (This seems to be an undocumented behavior. Not sure if it has been discussed in this site before. )

The following a minimal example illustrating 1st issue:

```
exprD /. n -> 0 /. x -> 0
(* 2/(3 Log[10]) <- incorrect, caused by the bug of DifferenceRoot *)

exprD /. x -> 0 /. n -> 0
(* 0 <- correct *)
```

As shown above, if the numeric value of `x` is substituted into `DifferenceRoot[…]` before that of `n`, the bug of `DifferenceRoot` is circumvented and the desired result is obtained. This is what has happened in `Plot` (when `Evaluate` has not involved in):

```
Plot[exprD /. n -> 0, {x, -1, 1.5}]
(* correct result *)
```

If the `HoldAll` attribute is cleared, the output will be incorrect:

```
ClearAttributes[Plot, HoldAll];

Plot[exprD /. n -> 0, {x, -1, 1.5}]
(* incorrect result *)

SetAttributes[Plot, HoldAll];
```

The interesting part is 3rd issue. We know that, as mentioned in the document of `Evaluate`:

> `Evaluate` only overrides `HoldFirst` etc. attributes when it appears directly as the head of the function argument that would otherwise be held.

In other words, `Evaluate` only temperally removes the `Hold*` attribute of the **contiguous** head. For example:

```
SetAttributes[fff, HoldAll]
fff[1 + 1 // Evaluate]
(* fff[2] *)

fff@g[1 + 1 // Evaluate]
(* fff[g[Evaluate[1 + 1]]] *)

fff@{1 + 1 // Evaluate}
(* fff[{Evaluate[1 + 1]}] *)
```

`fff@{1 + 1 // Evaluate}` "doesn't work" because `{}` is the shorthand of `List`, so `Evaluate` in code like

```
Plot[{Evaluate[exprD /. n -> 0]}, {x, -1, 1.5}]
```

should not have any effect in principle, but actually it's not the case. It turns out that `Plot` is handling `List` (`{}`) in a special way: **if 1st argument of `Plot` is a `List` `{}`, `Evaluate` contiguous to this `List` still breaks the `HoldAll` attribute of `Plot`**.

Finally, though not directly related, the following is another example showing `Plot`'s special handling for `List` (`{}`):

```
Plot[Table[x^i, {i, 2}], {x, -1, 1}]

list = {x, x^2};
Plot[list, {x, -1, 1}]
```

In principle 2nd plot should be the same as 1st one i.e. it should not use different color for different curves, but actually it's not the case.

Comment: Thank you for a clear and elaborate answer (quite educational, too!). While I do try very hard to investigate through reading all I can find in Mathematica Documentation, tutorials and guides, it is never a substitute for the wisdom of practical experience and deep understanding. Very helpful! (I agree that my presentations tend to be somewhat bloated with details, but at my, still not very confident level of using Mathematica, I am just trying to be exhaustive and 'convincing'. Will do a harder redacting in future.)

Answer (score 0):

A workaround using `Hold`:

Your code that works only inside `Plot` (i.e. plot is correct but the second line output is incorrect):

```
expr = -x 10^(-x^3);
exprD = D[expr, {x, n}];
Plot[Evaluate[exprD] /. n -> 0, {x, -1, 1.5}]
exprD/. n -> 0
```

[image]

And the workaround that works in both cases (i.e. plot is correct and correct is also the second line output):

```
expr = -x 10^(-x^3);
exprD = Hold[D[expr, {x, n}]];
Plot[Evaluate[exprD /. n -> 0 // ReleaseHold], {x, -1, 1.5}]
exprD /. n -> 0 // ReleaseHold
```

[image]

And regarding your question:

> What 'hidden' procedure (order of computation?), implemented with the
> `Plot[]` function, apparently circumvents the flaw that shows when
> computing the 0th derivative with a replacement rule `n−>0`?

I guess that `Plot` in your code uses `D[expr, {x, 0}]`, i.e. it replaces `n` with `0` before doing anything else. But why it is doing so I do not know. Maybe in the implementation of `Plot` there is somewhere used `Hold`/`ReleaseHold` like I used.

Comment: I am aware of possible ways to produce correct plots of the same expressions, intentionally. This is not the question. Please see my response to Michael E2's comment above. I am also aware that built-in functions in Mathematica incorporate procedures, the order of which can lead to one output instead of another. Unfortunately, my knowledge of the subtleties of the software is not that deep. About the Plot function, I can guess as much. The question is what specifically causes the inconsistency demonstrated in my question and how it can be utilised.

Comment: "I guess that Plot in your code uses `D[expr, {x, 0}]`, i.e. it replaces `n` with `0` before doing anything else. " The guess is not right. See the discussion in my answer.

Comment: My guess was more about using `Hold` inside `Plot` and that turned out to be true by your answer. `Hold` or `HoldAll`... the effect is the same

Comment: No, these are 2 different workarounds. Your solution is equivalent to circumventing the bug by avoiding symbolic `n` i.e. using `D[expr, {x, 0}]` so the `DifferenceRoot` is untouched, but in OP's `exprD`, the `DifferenceRoot` is already there. Notice your workaround require a modification for the definition of `exprD`, which is beyond the reach of `Plot`.