Plot and HoldAll
Can someone explain why the following works, despite Plot having the attribute HoldAll:
tmp = {x, x^2};
Plot[tmp, {x, 0, 1}]


Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/276177/1871 There should be more.
